# How to update multiple computers with QGIS on a network?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

We have ca. 30 Computers with QGIS 2.14 and I want to update them to QGIS 2.16 
for the first step and in the future simply update, when it's necessary.

The operating system is windows 7. I tried to make a configured installation like it is described in the following article http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/windows/
But the changed bat file doesn't work.

Has anyone experience with this?